# Sentence meaning and whether the word "derived" is used right here

Tags: word-choice, sentence-meaning

He **derived** from the letter that his lover had killed herself.

Can we use derive this way? 
Is the sentence grammatically correct and conveys the meaning that the speaker, after reading a letter, arrived at the conclusion that his lover had killed herself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes **derive** can be used to mean "obtain, get, extract":

> What advantage do you derive from that?
>
> What benefit can we derive from that?

"Clues" or "information" could be things derived.

> What information can we derive from this letter?

This particular usage, with information or details, is somewhat dated, not obsolete or archaic by any means, but something you might find in a 19th century novel.

Answer (score 0):

***[Derive:](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/derive)***

> If you say that something such as a word or feeling derives or is derived from something else, you mean that it comes from that thing.
>
> - Anna's strength is derived from her parents and her sisters. [be VERB-ed + from]
> - The word Easter derives from Eostre, the pagan goddess of spring. [VERB + from]

(Collins Dictionary)

In your sentence I’d use ***understood or learned***.

> she understood/learned from the letter...

Comment: Or deduced, maybe?